# Signalr - Override method for sending messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have an implementation of the `PersistentConnection` class in Signalr.  For our site, I need to be able to broadcast a message, and then have each connection determine whether that particular message is relevant for that specific user before sending it down the pipe to the browser.

Something like this:

```
public class MyConnection : PersistentConnection {

    private int _UserID;

    public override void OnSending(object message) {
        var msg = message as MyNotification;
        if(msg != null && !msg.CanRead(_UserID))
            return;
        base.OnSending(message);
    }

}
```

Is this possible?

Right now, we have a custom session state object.  Upon connection, the id is added to the users session object.  When we have a message to send out, we raise an event and each session determines whether to pass the message along to its associated client ids.  I really want to decouple this from our session object.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a hub pipeline module to get this affect.

For instance you can do:

```
public class MyModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    protected override bool OnBeforeOutgoing(IHubOutgoingInvokerContext context)
    {
        return context.Connection.ShouldSend();
    }
}
```

Then in your Application_Start:

```
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new MyModule());
```

Of course you would need to add the ShouldSend method to the IConnection interface and the corresponding connection objects but this would give you your desired result.

For more info on the the hub pipeline modules see the Hub Pipeline section at http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/11/11/microsoft-asp-net-signalr.aspx

Comment: That looks promising.  Let me check it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Most powerful features in the new version indeed. Was looking for this, thanks.

Comment: I was able to get all this wired up, but the context object doesn't have any object references for the client.  Is there a way to retrieve a Hub instance with a connectionId?

Comment: Really, I just need to access the IPrincipal associated with the Hub to know who is on the other end and then I can determine whether to send it to them.

Comment: I guess I could keep my own static ConcurrentDictionary of connectionId's and userId's, but I was kind of hoping for a better way...

Comment: So it looks like this won't work.  :[  The `IHubOutgoingInvokerContext` object does not have *any* information abou the client it's going to transmit to, and it's only called once for each message.

Comment: If you're using this for security purposes why not use the Authorize attribute?  You can check out the Authorize section in the link I posted.

Comment: Also, we recommend that you do keep your own list of connectionId's/userId's.  Secondly, with this mapping you can utilize the connectionId to determine who the message is going to etc.