# Monitoring SignalR message sizes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I am aware of a potential performance issue with SignalR when messages exceed 32K in size, what I would like to do is extend SignalR's normal process to check messages sizes and log if they exceed the 32K cutoff. I am trying to do so by registering custom types inheriting from SignalR's own types as documented here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility however the expected methods are not being hit when objects are pushed to clients from the server. Am I doing something wrong or is there an alternate way to monitor for objects exceeding the 32K size?

```
    public class MessageBusWithChecking : MessageBus
    {       
        public MessageBusWithChecking(IDependencyResolver resolver) : base(resolver)
        {

        }

        //This method is never hit
        public override Task Publish(Message message)
        {
            var messageSize = message.Value.Count();

            const int mem32K = 1024 * 32;
            if (messageSize > mem32K)
            {
                //Do Logging here
            }

            return base.Publish(message);
        }
    }

//App startup code...
public class Startup
    {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ...
            //Register custom class
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IMessageBus), () => new MessageBusWithChecking(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver));
            ...
        }
    }
```

I also attempted the same process as above with "IJsonSerializer" to no results as well.

Comment: Did you make sure that the hub is registered and active?

Comment: @Hozikimaru Yes. Hub is otherwise properly sending messages and they are being received on the client end.

Comment: Did you also tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442689/signalr-override-method-for-sending-messages

Comment: @Stephu the linked example seems to deal with hub and client information but nothing with accessing messages or their sizes